# WPF datagrid styling

Tags: .net, wpf

If there's only 1-2 records in the datagrid, and it has some height atleast for 10 rows. It shows the empty background and looks ugly, is there a way to show empty rows or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course show a semi-transparent/transparent background if you'd prefer...

```
<Style x:Key="Global_DataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.6" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

We keep a pretty background image behind, so a partially opaque background on the unused space looks nice too while still obviously reserving that screen real estate should there need to be more rows in the grid.

Comment: hm I do not think this is what NSingla wants here. From what I understand, he would like the vertical separation lines to go all the way down for instance.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_6.html

Look at these datagrids, looks elegant, gray vertical lines all the way down, no horizontal lines. I was able to do alternate colors, got rid of horizontal lines, and color vertical lines gray. But cant get the vertical lines all way down.

Comment: also if anybody knows, if i set row height more than default, how to align the text in center?

Comment: mydataGrid.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignments.Center));

Answer (score 0):

Something like following will work:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```